# How to graph $|y|=f(x)$?

Tags: graphing-functions

[image: Graph of |y|=F(x)]

This is the image of $|y|=F(x)$ , here the dotted part was the part of the original F(x) is the part that was cut off.

$$
  y =
\begin{cases}
F(x),  & \text{if $F(x) \ge 0$} \\
-F(x), & \text{if $F(x) < 0$}
\end{cases}
$$

if we use this then I afraid we get the wrong graph :?

Our graph in that case would like this : [image: Mod F(x)]

I am sorry if it is a silly doubt (Maybe am making a silly mistake `:/`) !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The graphs in the pictures are correct.

You have to interpret $|y|=f(x)$ and $y=|f(x)|$ as *relations* between real numbers. These relations can be graphed in the plane. They are *different* relations, as the pictures show.

When $f(x)<0$, there are no points $(x,y)$ such that $|y|=f(x)$.

When $f(x)\ge 0$, there are two points $(x,y)$ such that $|y|=f(x)$. They are $(x,\pm f(x))$.

Comment: when $F(x)<0$ it will become $y = -F(x)$ in that case , $(x,-y)$ would exist

Comment: Is it ... $F(x) = |y|$ therefore as the RHS is always positive the LHS should also be always positive ..... then I'm definitely wrong :(